# Access Web Apps - connecting to other databases

Tags: sharepoint-addin, access-services

I want to make an app that pulls data from a database that is not in any way related to Sharepoint, but it still lives on a SQL server, and I have to access it.

Is there a way to make for example a data macro to establish the connection and fire away queries?

Or should I go another way entirely if I want to do this sort of work - integrating Sharepoint with another database?

Answer (score 0):

Access Services does not have this capability, but the BCS service is designed for this.

Power User walkthrough:
http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/02/23/walkthrough-create-a-simple-bcs-connection-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Developer docs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782.aspx